# Toilet drain roughed in to wrong location

Tags: plumbing, toilet, rough-in

New construction home plumbing issue. Architects placed toilet in front of bathroom door. What the heck- that is where the sink should be! We did not notice until slab was poured and we saw the drain rough in. We want to move the drain at least 5 feet. This is a pier and beam foundation due to lake location and bad soil. Builder said he can cut into the slab, but I am concerned this will cause possible foundation or plumbing issues down the road. We could move the doorway but that means giving up valuable cabinet space. What would you do?

Comment: Diagram and /or pictures would be helpful.

Comment: Get the architect to pay - they screwed it up...

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: Could you take a picture of the floor plan of that bathroom and post it? We might be able to reconfigure the floor plan and find a solution without moving pipes. Otherwise we'll be able to tell you if the drafter is to blame.

Comment: I can not figure out how to upload the picture of the floor plan

Comment: To add a picture: [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/161816/edit) your question and click on the Photo icon in the editing interface. It's the one that looks like a mountain and a sun in a picture frame. Then browse for, drag/drop, or paste the image file.